# Every time i upgrade an App at App Store i need to change my icon again , how to change it?

Tags: icons, set, default

i changed my original icons in my iPhone 4 , it was great. The big problem is when an App need to be upgraded , my changed icon change to the default icon , so , every time i upgrade an App i need to go to my files and put my modified icon again.

It´s boring , what can i do to set my modified icon as default ?

Best Regards,

Att,

Glauber Felix

Comment: Why your default icon change to the default? I have some apps on the app Store and i have never faced this issue, maybe you are overwriting it with an old copy?